# Did Empire ever learn about Bail Organa's betrayal?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Bail Organa was killed when Death Star v1 destroyed Alderaan. But before that, did the Empire (or, Vader) ever learn that Bail Organa was working for enemies (Jedi and Rebel Alliances)?

Comment: Not in the main canon.

Comment: Give Star Wars Rebels a few more seasons to tell us that story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disney canon**

No information yet as of 12/2014.

---

**Legends (EU C-canon)** - Yes.

...

***Major spoilers for "The Force Unleashed" ahead!***

...

In the *Force Unleashed* (mostly-C-canon computer game), Darth Vader's secret apprentice Galen Marek had an assignment from Vader, to lure all the potential rebels into the open, under the pretense of creating an alliance to destroy the Emperor (and in reality, to flush them out and crush them), during the signing of  Corellian Treaty in ~2 BBY.

Vader and stormtroopers arrested Bail Organa, Mon Mothma, and Garm Bel Iblis, and took them to Death Star I to meet the Emperor and their doom.

But Galen Marek switched to the Light side, and at the cost of his own life bought the escape of the leaders of the soon-to-start Rebellion.

What really bakes my noodle is, why didn't Palpatine crush Organa in between 2BBY and Alderaan's destruction as per EU.

Comment: Not to mention why the Rebels somehow didn't find out about the Death Star until two years after they were on it!

Comment: @MiloPrice - do you mean to suggest that a random senator with no weapons technology background can figure out that an installation - of which they probably didn't get to see much of - is a planet busting superweapon?

Comment: I guess not, but still, originally the Rebels weren't supposed to have been aware of it at all until right before the time of ANH. I think the NPR dramatization goes into more detail of when exactly Bail learned about it.

Comment: one thing to keep in mind though is: From the inside the deathstar looked like any other empire insntallation. IT could have been just another asteroid that got rebuilt to become a station for tie squadrons,... .  As long as the later rebels dont see the weapon shaft or any other things that point to the REAL design of what they are on they wont know that its a moonsized weapon they are on.

Comment: Unsupported head canon, he gathered blueprints of the death star, but it took two years to Crack the encryption on the files.

Comment: According to the Legends EU, it wasn't until later that the Rebels caught wind of an Imperial "super-weapon". They hired mercenary Kyle Katarn to steal the plans, at which point they learned what the weapon was. The plans then passed from contact to contact until reaching Princess Leia and the ill-fated Tantive IV. That process took several months at least.